# AngularJS : WebSocket is closed before the connection is established in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, google-chrome

In Google Chrome, I am not able make socket connection to my server.
Getting Sometimes this in console (yellow colored):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=u_g7zfNFByPmMnnfAAAH' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

And after this (but not always):

```
POST http://www.mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1451326926027-5&sid=8MlGZTYdQ256ECoAAAAJ 400 (Bad Request)
```

Getting this in response :

```
{"code":1,"message":"Session ID unknown"}
```

**I have to refresh many times so the page can make connection.** 
In Firefox, same code is working fine most of the time but sometimes I get this.

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://www.mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=tDQpo6ynbIik6FUUAAAS.

instance = new WebSocket(uri);

socket.io.js (line 5310)

The connection to ws://www.mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=tDQpo6ynbIik6FUUAAAS was interrupted while the page was loading.

instance = new WebSocket(uri);
```

If I run my server in localhost the code is working fine in both the browser without any issue.
My server is in node.js running under nginx proxy. I configured nginx for socket support by following config : -

```
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

How I can assure that my websocket will connect without refreshing the page?
I implemented sockets in angular using [btford](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io).

Answer (score 1):

May I know your website hosted server

if its having dynamic session or dynamic token like getting changed in every call with the server then you may face this issue,capture Your dynamic session and append it in the URL Or add it to the header,it may help

Eg

WS://www.mywebsite.com;jsessionid=rbgeger377377

**Updated Answer**

I dont know that much about ubuntu server,

But in web socket ,initially a handshake will happen in that the session will be created and maintained throughout all request and response

if your session getting expired within some mins,probably the next session will replace the old session still you are doing request

Javascript is asynchronus if you have two concurrent services ,

Once session changed, by the time the next request getting initiated that time the session will not be available in your request ,but your server think its already changed,thats why you got the error think so,

I dont know the exact reason behind firefox and chrome ,Might be if you disabled the cache in chrome ,Lot of chance the next thread have to fail

In Javascript a good functionality is two way binding ,Once you got the new session in the response header ,if you mapped it to the url ,it will automatically bind to the next request ,using that you can avoid the problem think so

By clearing the cookies and cache during set of interval may help you to debug the issue

Comment: hosted server is ubuntu 64 bit server and how to get this dynamic session? and if this is the problem then why the code is working on firefox most of the time and on chrome sometimes

Comment: I updated my answer ,Commenting this seems to be not good :),Better luck :)

Comment: thanks @krishnakumar sekar . let me check if this works :) . I will update soon.